# disabling default print media query in zurb foundation 5 without using sass

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have been struggling with Print of of website page which are based on zurb foundation 5. When i print or print preview page it take the `medium` grid size by default & make it look different than the actual desktop version of the page.

I have looked for solution regarding a sass based solution is mentioned by most but i am not using sass or familiar with it. Isnt their a simple version of  foundation that comes with  disable print option so that desktop page print as this showup on screen.

I know this is mobile first but user dont print from their mobile device as they print from desktop.

A solution with sass is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can take the large grid size css from foundation.css and copy it and put it in a new css file called
`print.css' and then insert it at the head like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

this will make sure you use the large grid for printing

alternatively you can also do this

```
 @media print {

 }
```